# How to assign different IP addresses to remote users?

Tags: remote-desktop

I run a few remote users on my Windows PC using a program that allows me to bypass the limit of Windows Home. I can access them all while running my own instance. I use them for gaming in multiple instances.

Now I want to assign them different IP addresses so that the server I am connecting to does not see there are 50 users on the same ip address. How do I achieve this?

I know that I can assign multiple IPs in Windows using a single Ethernet port. I also would need to mask MAC address of each instance if possible (can do it mb with router).

Comment: You're going about this fundamentally wrong.  You don't assign a user an IP, instead you bind each instance of your gaming client to a different IP that is assigned to the machine.  How you do that (or if you even can) will depend on the gaming client.